# Using XPath Axes to Locate Same Node in Preceding Ancestor with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm new to XPath expressions in XSLT and have hit my head against the desk for too long. I'd like to evaluate a sibling node within the first preceding ancestor of the current node and test if that node is the same.

Here's my XML:

```
<item>
    <number>1.0</number>
    <category>Data</category>
    <functionality>Search Screen</functionality>
    <requirement_type>SIT</requirement_type>
    <table>Table</table>
</item>
<item>
    <number>1.1</number>
    <category>Data</category>
    <functionality>Search Screen</functionality>
    <requirement_type>SIT</requirement_type>
</item>
```

Here's my XSLT:

```
<xsl:for-each select="item">
  <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::*[position()=1])">
    <xsl:value-of select="category"/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Essentially, I'm trying to test whether the `<category>` child node of the the second `<item>` node is the same as the `<category>` child node of the the first `<item>` node.

Searching similar StackOverflow questions gets me close, but just not there ....

Comment: "*I'm trying to test whether the <category> child node of the the second <item> node is the same as the <category> child node of the the first <item> node.*"  For what purpose? it seems like you are trying to group the items by category, or get the distinct categories (same thing, really). If so, do a search for *grouping* (probably the most often asked question here).

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to group the items by category. Basically, I want to get a distinct group of items within one category. Thanks @michael.hor257k, I'll give that search a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a well-formed input document that has a single outermost element. Also, as you can see, I have added an `id` attribute to the `item` elements to be able to tell them apart.

**XML Input**

```
<root>
    <item id="1">
        <number>1.0</number>
        <category>Data</category>
        <functionality>Search Screen</functionality>
        <requirement_type>SIT</requirement_type>
        <table>Table</table>
    </item>
    <item id="2">
        <number>1.1</number>
        <category>Data</category>
        <functionality>Search Screen</functionality>
        <requirement_type>SIT</requirement_type>
    </item>
</root>
```

To find out whether the `category` child element of the immediately preceding sibling `item` element is the same, you could use

```
<xsl:if test="category = preceding-sibling::item[1]/category">
```

If the semantics should actually be different, you really need to explain this more clearly, perhaps also modifying the sample document.

**XSLT Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/root">
      <result>
            <xsl:for-each select="item">
              <xsl:if test="category = preceding-sibling::item[1]/category">
                <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
              </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
      </result>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>2</result>
```

Try this transformation online [here](http://xsltransform.net/jyH9rMK).

---

**EDIT**

> Yes, I'm trying to group the items by category. Basically, I want to get a distinct group of items within one category.

For completeness, then, as Michael has noted, you are trying to solve a *grouping* problem. In XSLT 1.0, use a *key* and do Muenchian grouping. In XLST 2.0, use `xsl:for-each-group`. You'll easily find examples for both techniques.

Comment: That works. I used your if branch and tweaked the test attribute:
<xsl:if test="category != preceding-sibling::item[position()=1]/category">

Thanks!

Comment: @Tony You are welcome. Please either [accept my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it satisifes you, or, as Michael notes above, explain the _problem_ you are facing. Then, there might be an even more elegant solution.

Comment: appreciate the response and help marking the answer to correct. Also, the link you posted is very cool.

Comment: @Tony Added some notes on grouping.